# need to add field in particular section but it will add in all section on click of every section button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

[image: like this image i need to add fields per section but on add button it will add in all section i need it will add on particular section so how to add in react]
**please any one help me out from this situation and also how I will every section array in one array thank you so much.**

[click on this link and check the code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-input-fields-reactjs-tpebqh?file=src%2FApp.js)

Comment: This is because you need to control if it appear depending on `i`. you need `if i == <the particular section number> then <code for specific field>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**known number of sections**

This is a minimal and complete example. The goal is to keep the application simple and put the component logic in the same place as the individual components. The use of custom hooks is suitable for this particular problem.

```js
function App() {
  const [names1, component1] = useNames([{first: "mu", last: "yanling"}])
  const [names2, component2] = useNames([])
  const [names3, component3] = useNames([{first: "chandra", last: "nalaar"}])
  return <div>
    <p>Section 1</p>{component1}
    <p>Section 2</p>{component2}
    <p>Section 3</p>{component3}
    <pre>{JSON.stringify({names1, names2, names3}, null, 2)}</pre>
  </div>
}

function useNames(initNames = []) {
  const [names, setNames] = React.useState(initNames)
  function add(event) {
    setNames([...names, {first: "", last: ""}])
  }
  function update(index, part) { return event =>
    setNames([
      ...names.slice(0, index),
      { ...names[index], [part]: event.target.value },
      ...names.slice(index + 1)
    ])
  }
  function remove(index) { return event =>
    setNames([...names.slice(0, index), ...names.slice(index + 1)])
  }
  return [
    names,
    <div>
      {names.map((n, key) =>
        <div key={key}>
          <input onChange={update(key, "first")} value={n.first} />
          <input onChange={update(key, "last")} value={n.last} />
          <button type="button" onClick={remove(key)} children="❌" />
        </div>
      )}
      <button type="button" onClick={add} children="⭐️" />
    </div>
  ]
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.14.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.14.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

**varying number of sections**

Hooks cannot be called in a loop or in a conditional. If you have a variable amount of sections a different technique is needed. In this code each section can be represented by a new object key in the state.

```js
function App() {
  const [sections, setSections] = React.useState({
    "section1": [{first: "mu", last: "yanling"}],
    "section2": [],
    "section3": [{first: "chandra", last: "nalaar"}]
  })
  // ...
}
```

To handle the nested state, the codes below use immutable helpers `oupdate`, `aupdate`, `aremove` to modify objects and arrays.

```js
// immutable helpers
function oupdate(obj, key, f) {
  return { ...obj, [key]: f(obj[key]) }
}

function aupdate(arr, key, f) {
  return [...arr.slice(0, key), f(arr[key]), ...arr.slice(key + 1)]
}

function aremove(arr, key) {
  return [...arr.slice(0, key), ...arr.slice(key + 1)]
}
```

The `add`, `update`, and `remove` functions are modified to pay respect to the new section keys of the state.

```js
function App() {
  const [sections, setSections] = React.useState({
    "section1": [{first: "mu", last: "yanling"}],
    "section2": [],
    "section3": [{first: "chandra", last: "nalaar"}]
  })
  function add(section){ return event =>
    setSections(
      oupdate(sections, section, names =>
        [...names, {first: "", last: ""}]
      )
    )
  }
  function update(section, index, part) { return event =>
    setSections(
      oupdate(sections, section, names =>
        aupdate(names, index, name =>
          oupdate(name, part, _ => event.target.value)
        )
      )
    )
  }
  function remove(section, index) { return event =>
    setSections(
      oupdate(sections, section, names =>
        aremove(names, index)
      )
    )
  }
  // ...
}
```

A nested loop is required to loop through the section keys and the names for each section.

```js
function App() {
  // ...
  return <div>
    {Object.entries(sections).map(([section, names]) =>
      <div>
        <p>{section}</p>
        {names.map((n, key) =>
          <div key={key}>
            <input onChange={update(section, key, "first")} value={n.first} />
            <input onChange={update(section, key, "last")} value={n.last} />
            <button type="button" onClick={remove(section, key)} children="❌" />
          </div>
        )}
        <button type="button" onClick={add(section)} children="⭐️" />
      </div>
    )}
    <pre>{JSON.stringify(sections, null, 2)}</pre>
  </div>
}
```

**demo**

```js
function oupdate(obj, key, f) {
  return { ...obj, [key]: f(obj[key]) }
}

function aupdate(arr, key, f) {
  return [...arr.slice(0, key), f(arr[key]), ...arr.slice(key + 1)]
}

function aremove(arr, key) {
  return [...arr.slice(0, key), ...arr.slice(key + 1)]
}

function App() {
  const [sections, setSections] = React.useState({
    "section1": [{first: "mu", last: "yanling"}],
    "section2": [],
    "section3": [{first: "chandra", last: "nalaar"}]
  })
  function add(section){ return event =>
    setSections(
      oupdate(sections, section, names =>
        [...names, {first: "", last: ""}]
      )
    )
  }
  function update(section, index, part) { return event =>
    setSections(
      oupdate(sections, section, names =>
        aupdate(names, index, name =>
          oupdate(name, part, _ => event.target.value)
        )
      )
    )
  }
  function remove(section, index) { return event =>
    setSections(
      oupdate(sections, section, names =>
        aremove(names, index)
      )
    )
  }
  
  return <div>
    {Object.entries(sections).map(([section, names]) =>
      <div>
        <p>{section}</p>
        {names.map((n, key) =>
          <div key={key}>
            <input onChange={update(section, key, "first")} value={n.first} />
            <input onChange={update(section, key, "last")} value={n.last} />
            <button type="button" onClick={remove(section, key)} children="❌" />
          </div>
        )}
        <button type="button" onClick={add(section)} children="⭐️" />
      </div>
    )}
    <pre>{JSON.stringify(sections, null, 2)}</pre>
  </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.14.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.14.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

You may consider using a module like [Immutable](https://immutable-js.com/) to make it easier to update nested state in your React apps. This saves you from writing the immutable helpers manually but comes as a cost of adding a dependency.

Comment: thank you so much for your help ,I need section wise array

Comment: `[...names1, ...names2, ...names3]` produces one array but I changed to `{names1, names2, names3}` to give you sectioned output. Is that what you mean?

Comment: so how to dynamically generate sections on API indexes like if get API give's the 3 section then generate 3 section if 2 then generate 2 section, so how to dynamically generate the 
`const [names2, component2] = useNames([])` State .

Comment: @AbdulMunim if there is a varying amount of sections a different technique is required. I updated my answer to show one possibility.

Comment: okay this is great, I will use your new technique  but on which function i will apply loop can you mention please, I am confusing

Comment: The loops are used in the render (`return`) portion of the component. `Object.entries(sections).map(([section, names]) => ...)` is the outer loop and `names.map((n, key) => ...)` is the inner loop. The demo includes a working example.

Answer (score 2):

From the code you submit, you have an Array length 3 that maps over the same JSX 3 times. As a result, you are creating 3 JSX instances that all point to the same state, hence the reason why they all changing the same.

You need to separate them. Instead of mapping them over a random array, Map over the state itself. This way each JSX will point to each object of the state, which I guess is the behavior you want here. But keep in mind you might want to find out how to map over the object properties and add new fields based on each object.
For example, if you want an age field and title field on the second section, the state should look like this `[{firstName: "", lastName: ""}, {firstName: "", lastName: "", age: "", title: ""}]`

```
const [inputList, setInputList] = useState([{firstName: '', lastName: '' }, {firstName: '', lastName: '' },{firstName: '', lastName: '' }])
 return <>{inputList.map(i => (<>
            <input value={i.firstName}/>
            <input value={i.lastName} />
           </> )}</>
```